# How is my question off-topic?

Tags: discussion

My question, [Utility company wants me to sign easement contract for $1](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/95720/utility-company-wants-me-to-sign-easement-contract-for-1) has been closed as off-topic.  I would like to know why.  I don't see this as being any different from asking about selling a house and how to determine what the price should be.  I am certainly not asking for legal advice as one commenter implied.

Answer (score 2):

If I was going to write answer to your question it would have several key points:

1) read the entire contract.
2) see what easements are currently on the recorded property documents.
3) consult a local real estate attorney to see what are your options.

Beyond that I don't know what else to say.

which is why there was a comment about it being a legal issue.

Comment: Well a warning about it decreasing the value of my propery would have been helpful as would some hint of how to estimate either the decrease in value or the or the value of the easement.  An easement is just a fancy way of saying your selling some rights, it's no more or less a legal issue than selling your house or car.